# Stored procedure output parameter value is null (entity framework)

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am trying to call a stored procedure from entity framework but I am unable to get the output parameter value. It is always returning null.
Here is my code

```
object[] parameters = {
    new SqlParameter("@Date", date),
    new SqlParameter("@outDate", SqlDbType.Date) {Direction= ParameterDirection.Output}
};
int defval = context.Database.CommandTimeout.Value;
context.Database.CommandTimeout = 1800;
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("dbo.TestDateFormatAndRegion @Date, @outDate", parameters);
var NoOfSyncOperationsDeleted = parameters[1].ToString();
```

Can you please help.

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you use `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("dbo.TestDateFormatAndRegion @Date, @outDate OUTPUT", parameters);`?

Comment: It actually executes the stored procedure but I am unable to get value in output parameter.

Comment: So including `OUTPUT` in the command made no difference?

Comment: No, it did not help.

Comment: Interesting... [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vda2T_T1)

Comment: Yes, when exec the stored procedure in SQL Server then I get the value. But the issue is in calling the stored procedure from the entity framework.

Comment: Specify the parameters explicitly, in case the order is different `EXEC dbo.TestDateFormatAndRegion @Date = @Date, @outDate = @outDate OUTPUT`

Comment: Have a look at my blog post here: https://erikej.github.io/efcore/2020/08/03/ef-core-call-stored-procedures-out-parameters.html

Answer (score 1):

In the `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` call, modified the SQL command to use `EXEC` to explicitly execute the stored procedure and add `OUTPUT` to the `@outDate` parameter.

```
object[] parameters = {
    new SqlParameter("@Date", date),
    new SqlParameter("@outDate", SqlDbType.Date) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output }
};

int defaultTimeout = context.Database.CommandTimeout.Value;
context.Database.SetCommandTimeout(1800);

context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC dbo.TestDateFormatAndRegion @Date, @outDate OUTPUT", parameters);

var outputParameter = parameters[1].Value;
```

Comment: It's not working still.
It was working without EXEC. I mean stored procedure was executing but the output parameter was not getting value after executing the stored procedure.